# Typescript errors for function return types

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm using Typescript with Node and am getting some errors I don't quite understand.

index.ts

```
import read_json_remote from './toolkit/read_json_remote';    
const url: string = 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/significant_month.geojson';    
read_json_remote(url).then(data => {
    console.log(data.features);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

read_json_remote.ts

```
import got from 'got';
export default (url: string) => {
    return got(url).then((res: object) : object =>  {
        return JSON.parse(res.body);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
};
```

VSCode shows an error on:

```
return JSON.parse(res.body);
```

in read_json_remote.ts that says the property 'body' does not exist on the object 'res'.

When I console.log res, I see the 'body' property there, in accordance with what is in the Got documentation.

I'm obviously new to Typescript, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Api is returning response in JSON , so no need to use JSON.parse() .

```
import got from 'got';
export default (url: string) => {
    return got(url).then((res: object) : object =>  {
        return res;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
};
```